# strange uitableview top border only on iphone 5 simulator 4 inch

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

when I run the app on iphone 4 simulator or device, there is no topborder.
the border is not the uitableview.layer.border, it's moves with the content scroll.

I've tried to change and test the cell border, the table seperator..
but, I can't remove this strange gray border.

I also test to see if this border was hidden behind subview in iphone 4, but no,
on the iphone 4, the border is not exist.

again, only in iphone 5 simulator (I don't have device to test on).

any ideas ?

UPDATE:
well..
I manually add border to the layer of the uitableview.
unlucky then, but..it's better late then never..

Comment: Could be helpful to add a screenshot

Comment: @Tim Windsor Brown,  it's just top border that look like if it on the first cell (move with the scroll), but it appear even when the table is empty.

Comment: Is it that when you tested your app on iPhone 4 simulator and device, it was `iOS6` and the iPhone 5 simulator was in `iOS7`?

Comment: @user1190882 all testing with ios7 only.
with iphone4 device and iphone4 simulator = no strange top border.
with iphone5 simulator there is strange top border.

if this is matter, the uitableview is subview of uitableviewcell.

Comment: As mentioned, screenshots would give us a better idea what is going on...

Comment: well..
I manually add border to the layer of the uitableview.
unlucky then, but..it's better late then never..